# Deserialise JSON with variable names

Tags: c#, json

I would like to deserialise a JSON file in C# so each order is on a seperate line with all values possible. I don't have a problem with deserialising a JSON but this one has variable attribute names. In example, the file below has 2 order: O1ZBIX-GGYTG-RJVXNK & ORJZUB-AL7JW-7BBWPZ. Please advice how i can do this.

```
{
  "error": [],
  "result": {
    "open": {
      "O1ZBIX-GGYTG-RJVXNK": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": null,
        "status": "open",
        "opentm": 1486584202.2485,
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "pair": "XBTEUR",
          "type": "sell",
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "1019.000",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "order": "sell 0.20809000 XBTEUR @ limit 1019.000"
        },
        "vol": "0.20809000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fciq"
      },
      "ORJZUB-AL7JW-7BBWPZ": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": null,
        "status": "open",
        "opentm": 1486468345.44,
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "pair": "LTCEUR",
          "type": "sell",
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "3.78000",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "order": "sell 54.20054000 LTCEUR @ limit 3.78000"
        },
        "vol": "54.20054000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fciq"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you deserialize each order key to a `Dictionary<string, MyType>`?

Comment: Both orders have exactly the same number, order and naming of keys.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of Json.Net from http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Then just use `JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);`